# WCF Data Services Security Options

Tags: wcf-data-services

What options are there for securing WCF Data Services?  The open, RESTful nature of the services are extremely beneficial but I need to lock these services down so that only my Silverlight and WPF apps can perform requests against these services.  The app will be distributed publicly, but our data and data model are not free for public consumption.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides all the things already mentioned, WCF Data Services also have a concept called [Query Interceptors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842%28VS.100%29.aspx) which allows you on a programmatic basis to decide whether or not a given caller should be able to see all, some or no data at all.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, as it is the most relevant to the specific Use Case of WCF Data Services.

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735093.aspx

Simple transport level security, which could be SSL.  Or Message Security which could involve sending credentials in the soap header (WS-* standards).

Comment: Do the same security mechanisms work with WCF Data Services?  Also, with the transport level security if I add certificate level security that would mean that only applications that possess the security ticket can access my webservice?  No one else would be able to access it?

Answer (score 1):

Transfer security - SSL, credentials - CardSpace, certificates... http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/Wikipage

Comment: Do these pertain to WCF Data Services?  Or just WCF Services?

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean. WCF is a framework or interface if you want that is used generally by WCF Services, in our case Data Services (Data Services, Sharepoint Services, Azure etc.). Those are only frameworks. Same as Clients Data Service (Silverlight, AJAX etc.). So if you want ie. AJAX, or your app to consume your data securely, you have to secure the transfer of the data over HTTP (SSL) and so you have to secure credentials (ie. login + password)... Generally it doesn't matter what services are you using. There is always a distributed app and you should protect transfered data.